# Dataframe to dictionary merging keys in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe as you can see in below:

[image]

Some `pro1`'s have different `pro2`'s.

I want to convert this dataframe to dictionary as:

```
bundles = {
    '12345' : ['a1','b1','c1','e1'],
    '56789' : ['a1'],
    '98765' : ['b1','d1']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` on `pro1` and create a list from `pro2`, finally convert to a dictionary:

```
out = df.groupby('pro1')['pro2'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Comment: Per some benchmarks I'm running, `apply` is actually just a tiny bit faster than `agg`.

Answer (score 1):

```
bundles = df.groupby('pro1')['pro2'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
>>> bundles
{
    '12345': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'e1'],
    '56789': ['a1'],
    '98765': ['b1', 'd1']
}
```